# Are there terminal blocks that are quick to attach for use in a production environment?

Tags: connector, wire-terminals, terminal-block

Is there a connector that I can use with a tinned wire that's easy to attach, are there any solutions available?

I would use a terminal block but having to screw/unscrew several wires in a testing environment will add to production time.

Comment: Is the tinned wire attached to the unit to be tested or to the test equipment? If it's attached to the test equipment, can it have anything added to it, like a ferrule, to improve reliability/durability?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard way to do this in a manufacturing environment is to use [test fixture grabbers](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=test_fixture_grabbers) (my site).

They work with any wire, some even with unstripped wire (they perforate the insulation).

[image: E-Z-Nailclip 82-2]

{My picture}

[image: Test grabber with wire]

{My picture}

Comment: Oh! These are really nice!

Comment: These look good.

Answer (score 8):

There's Wago-clamp style "lever-fixer" screwless terminal blocks.

[image: WAGO Cage clamp]

Wago specifies these for stranded and solid wires, bare or crimped to a ferrule.

Similar ideas exist in varying degrees of beefiness. This thing is for 25 mm² to 95 mm² conductors.

[image: Heavy screwless terminal]

A much cheaper version might be clamping speaker connectors, but these might need a little more attention to actual connection for reliability.

[image: Plasty McPlastiface Speaker connector array]

Comment: I was going to point out Euroblock until I got to thinking "I wonder if there's a version that has a modular connector on the board like Euroblock, but uses Wago-style levers instead of screws for the individual wires". Seems like the LPC is exactly that.

Comment: I think Vincent's suggestion is the right answer for this question, unless there's something else the author didn't mention there. Neatly qualifies as a quick-release terminal block. Hard to imagine a better fit.

Comment: Tool less terminal block are only rated for a few insertions, if you are doing any sort of volume, I wouldn't use those. Speaker terminal are better suited.

Answer (score 6):

An exemple a PCB version is available at :

https://www.phoenixcontact.com/en-in/new-products/new-products-device-connection-technology/lever-actuated-pcb-terminal-blocks-and-pcb-connectors

or

https://www.wago.com/us/pcb-interconnect/terminal-strip-with-angled-push-buttons/p/256-405_334-000

These connectors increase reliability because they do not unscrew over time. Implentation example in old design :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't going directly to a PCB, the Wago 222/221 series are a good option for connecting wires with quick attachment and easy removal. They also make mounting carriers to hold them in place.

[image]