# Barrier block vs. Lever wire splice for power distribution in a mobile robot

Tags: connector, wire-terminals, terminal-block

I am a beginner in robotics and am learning by building a four-wheel mobile robot. I will supply electrical power from one Li-ion battery to four DC motors. I plan to use a barrier block to distribute power. Today, I came to know about lever wire splices. If I have to use the barrier blocks, I will have to crimp ring terminals at the end of wires. But, if I use a lever wire connector, I won't have to crimp any terminals; I can simply insert the wire ends into the splice. So, I am considering using a lever wire splice instead of a power terminal block.

As a beginner, I am wondering whether my decision is correct. Can you share the pros and cons of the barrier block and lever wire splice?

[image]

Comment: Skim [this question and its answers](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/676973/330261) for additional thoughts and ideas.

Comment: Thank you for the sharing the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is a "barrier block" and a "lever wire splice".

> Can you share the pros and cons of the barrier block and lever wire splice?

Between the two, the barrier block is definitely better because it's mounted to a panel (the lever wire splice will bang around, and that's not good).

Your perceived advantage of the lever splice is not an advantage because a) you don't have to crimp a ring terminal to the wires with a barrier block and b) you could crimp a ferrule to the wires with a lever splice. So, in either case, you can use bare wires or wires crimped to a terminal.

However, let me suggest other components you should consider instead:

- [Rail mounted terminal blocks](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=din_35mm_rail_terminal_blocks) (my site) -- available in screwless, inclduding lever.
- [Single-ended junction posts](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=junction_posts) -- perfect for high current.
- [Junction bus bars](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=junction_bars) -- Great to distribute power
- [Terminal Junction Systems](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=terminal_junction_systems) -- Truly professional
- [Neutral blocks](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=neutral_blocks) -- Cheap alternative at your local hardware store
- [Eurostyle terminal strips](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NN&n=eurostyle_terminal_strips) -- Old standard in Europe

Comment: Thank you for replying to my query. An attachment will come with the lever package so that the lever can be attached to a panel. Also, thank you again for the additional component suggestions.